# How to use index.php for directories - htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a directory named 'appfolder'.
I have used the following `.htaccess` for using for every unknown file to use **index.php**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

If I open domain.com/appfolder it gives me the default apache forbidden page instead of using index.php

How can I also set to use **index.php** for directories in **.htaccess**

Comment: For that you first have to find out _why_ you get that "forbidden" error. Please take a look into your http servers error log file. You should find some more specific reason there.

Comment: This is the default in apache for not to list directorys and give a forbidden error.

I am asking how to use index.php for existing directories.

Comment: That is not the question at hand, sorry. If your rewriting rules work (I assume you tested that...), then you do not want to use the "builtin" directory index feature at all. What I meant with my questions is: there are different reasons that can lead to the error your describe. Without knowing _which_ of the different reasons is responsible it is _much_ harder to solve the issue. So why don't you simply take a look into that log file?

Comment: answer provided by @anubhava is **exactly** what I wanted 
and 

thank you **arkascha** for your precaution comments

Comment: OK, great that you solved the issue by that "blind shot". But do yourself a favor and find out about that http servers error log file. You will need it again and again. You cannot operate an http server without that.

Comment: I myself have enabled to give forbidden server error in my server settings. So is not the issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109074/discussion-between-abrar-ahmed-and-arkascha).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I also set to use index.php for directories in .htaccess

Remove this condition:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

**Full .htaccess:**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```